# Chains of approximate numeric equalities

Tags: numerics, evaluation, inequalities, numerical-value

Mathematica considers two numbers equal if "at most their last seven binary digits" differ. For example:

```
In[1]:= ep = 2.5*^-14;

In[2]:= E == E + ep     (* Less than 7 binary digits *)
Out[2]= True

In[3]:= E == E + 2 ep   (* More than 7 *)
Out[3]= False
```

This seems strange but I understand the motivation. 
I then wondered if it's possible to construct a chain of equalities with unequal ends but nevertheless evaluates to `True`. It turns out no:

```
In[4]:= E + ep == E + 2 ep
Out[4]= True

In[5]:= E == E + ep == E + 2 ep   (* First and last argument differ *)
Out[5]= False
```

However, if you use `LessEqual` (which behaves similarly to Equal) it is possible:

```
In[6]:= E + 2 ep <= E + ep <= E  (* Expected False *)
Out[6]= True

In[7]:= E + 2 ep <= E            (* As in Equal *)
Out[7]= False
```

My question is, is there a reason for this odd behaviour or is it just a quirk to be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all explained in the Documentation Center.

[`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)

> Subscript[e, 1] == Subscript[e, 2] == Subscript[e, 3] gives True if all the Subscript[e, i] are equal.

[`LessEqual`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LessEqual.html)

> Subscript[x, 1] <= Subscript[x, 2] <= Subscript[x, 3] yields True if the Subscript[x, i] form a nondecreasing sequence.

That is, the three arguments in `Equal` must be equal in all possible pairings; the three arguments in `LessEqual` must satisfy the indicated relation only as adjacent pairs; i.e., in a chain.

Another way of thinking about this difference in behavior is that `Equal` is reflexive, commutative, and transitive, while `LessEqual` is only reflexive and transitive. (And `Less` is only transitive.) Being commutative requires the checking of all pairings.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer since it's too long for a comment.

m_goldberg suggests that all pairs must be compared but that's not the full story, consider

```
In[1]:= a == 2 == 3   (* Expect False *)
Out[1]= a == 2 == 3

In[2]:= 2 == 3 == a
Out[2]= False
```

Doing some experiments it appears that all pairs of arguments are compared in lexicographic order; if two elements are pairwise unequal then return False, if they're not comparable return the expression unevaluated, otherwise return True.

Whether an expression is False or unevaluated depends on whether an unequal or incomparable pair is encountered first.

Comment: What you discuss in this answer is the behavior of all Mathematica relational operators. It can be summed up by saying they are not predicates.